# How to set horizontal to list vertical li ul

Tags: css, asp.net

I need your help!
I have a image to show my problem

[image]

I want to use CSS to do this, and don't use anymore div or element because I code this in ASP.NET. Each item is showed from database.

Example:
ASP code:

```
<ul id="vitravleNav" name="vitravleNav">
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dulich %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT top(8) [tenmenu], [urlhinh] FROM [menu] WHERE anhien=1">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <a href="<%# Eval("urlhinh") %>" title="<%# Eval("tenmenu") %>" ><im<%#Eval("tenmenu") %></a>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

</ul>
```

CSS code:

```
#vitravleNav
{
    margin: 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    letter-spacing: -0.5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 3px #202020;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#vitravleNav li
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    width: 12.3%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color: #0099FF;
}
#vitravleNav li:hover
{
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px 4px white;
}
#vitravleNav li a
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    line-height: 50px;
    outline: none;
    padding-top:40px;
}
```

Here is the HTML output image: http://i1265.photobucket.com/albums/jj507/mabonblog/3_zps02c6598a.png

Comment: please show the rendered html and css you have tried

Comment: @Pete: I have edited. Please help me!

Comment: Do you need a css menu? If so go and check out http://cssmenumaker.com/

Comment: I think what @Pete really asked was for generated HTML - right now you are sharing ASP Code.

Comment: @Gohomeurdrunk: what do you mean? What should I do to resolved this problem? Should I replace ul li by div?

Comment: @Imran Bughio: I write my problem with ASP in my question :).

Comment: Please view the web page in your browser and post the HTML markup found when using view source.

Comment: @xDaevax: http://i1265.photobucket.com/albums/jj507/mabonblog/3_zps02c6598a.png

Comment: you could use column-width, an height on ul and float lis. your html sent to the browser is needed to see what you deal with

Comment: @GCyrillus: Sorry, I don't understand you :(

Comment: We need to see the HTML produce by asp. look at souce from your browser and copy/paste it into a fiddle width CSS too. So it reproduce what you get. we can help you from there. this is what everybody keeps asking here.

Comment: It's not an answer, but here is what I got (maybe someone else can build on it): http://jsfiddle.net/xDaevax/3jQ4Q/  Your solution can't be just CSS (I think), you'll need to adjust your repeaters as well, or at least the logic in them.

Comment: @xDaevax: Thank you so much for your help! Maybe I need to change the logic of this. thank again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by using nth-of-type-pseudo selectors: [on w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo)

```
#vitravleNav li {
  position: absolute
  ...
}

#vitravleNav li:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: 25%
}

#vitravleNav li:nth-of-type(5) {
  left: 50%
}

#vitravleNav li:nth-of-type(6) {
  left: 70%
}
```

You could find a demo here, on: [dabblet](http://result.dabblet.com/gist/21a0ecc8c009059abc0c/753453725a6aa3ed37870cca8f9e93d2ec0302ad) or [with code on dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/21a0ecc8c009059abc0c).
Code as [gist on github](https://gist.github.com/21a0ecc8c009059abc0c/753453725a6aa3ed37870cca8f9e93d2ec0302ad).

With best regards.

Comment: Clean solution as long as the list doesn't change.  Nicely done all in the same level of nesting within the UL so OP doesn't have to change their code that much.

Comment: You are right, @xDaevax. It should not change that much. Thanks for this addition.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no `HTML` to relay on, i'll devellop idea from my comments here.

You look like you want to wrap your element in rows and column and fill up space as much as possible.

items seems to have predefined size.

For the `column-width` + `height` idea, see this demo with images from on a 200px square at most.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zoCvL)**

---

BASIC rules to start with:

```
li, img {
  float:left;
  display:block;/* kills bullet*/
}
ul, li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
ul {
  column-width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
```

**[DEMO with border and margin.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CAqGH)**

---

Else,

you have the masonry script with options :

http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html

that can be an hint too.

Comment: Nice link, I'll definitely be saving that one for later.

Comment: seem you use javascript to fix this. But i don't understand your js, so i can't adjust it for my case. [joking] I tried use your js file, but it not working

Comment: @kidsoul The demo is not using javascript at all :) , only for prefix-vendor within the setting of codepen.

Comment: but why i tried to use your js, it's not working as your demo?

Comment: @kidsoul there is no javascript involved, just the column properties and an height. add prefix like -moz- or -webkit- if needed . you can download the demo files from a zip http://codepen.io/anon/share/zip/zoCvL/